# ¿Como puedo realizar una búsqueda de un formato de fecha en horario local (México), cuando en la base de datos viene con horario Z?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Hola comunidad de programadores(as), soy nuevo en este grupo, así como también en la programación, estoy trabajando con la arquitectura MVC con Node.js, MySQL, Express.js y JavaScript, estoy realizando una vista de sesiones, en la cual tengo una tabla en donde muestro usuario, hora de entrada, hora de salida, ultimo monitoreo y el status de la sesión, también tengo un campo de búsqueda, para buscar por los campos mencionados anteriormente, en mi modelo de sesiones realizo una consulta a la base de datos para filtrar los resultados, muestro los resultados a la vista con JavaScript, la consulta viene con fechas y horarios Z (UTC), con JavaScript hago la conversión a mi horario local que es México y la muestro en la vista, cuando realizo una búsqueda por alguna fecha u hora, me trae los resultados en horario local pero no coincide con la búsqueda porque la consulta la realiza con horario Z, como puedo hacer que mi consulta sea con la conversión de horario local, ejemplo: realizo una búsqueda con numero 15, quiero que muestre todos los resultados que tengan un 15 y la vista me devuelve resultados que no contienen 15, haciendo un log y revisando el porque, me doy cuenta que aunque se hace la conversión, la consulta sigue siendo en horario Z, espero y me haya explicado de la mejor manera, espero me puedan apoyar.
adjunto código de mi modelo de sesiones, de mi controlador y de mi JavaScript:

```
 export const sesiones_busqueda = async(data) => {
try {
    const [sesiones, metadata] = await db.query(`
    SELECT 
        session_start,
        session_end,
        (session.session_start) AS sesion_ultimo_monitoreo,
        IF (session.session_status = "A", "Activa", "Cerrada") AS sesion_status,
        user.user_name
    FROM session
        JOIN user ON session.user_id = user.user_id
    WHERE
        session_start LIKE '%${data.busqueda}%' OR
        session_end LIKE '%${data.busqueda}%' OR
        (session.session_start) LIKE '%${data.busqueda}%' OR
        (IF (session.session_status = "A", "Activa", "Cerrada")) LIKE '%${data.busqueda}%' OR
        user.user_name LIKE '%${data.busqueda}%'
        ORDER BY session_start DESC
        LIMIT ${data.inicio}, ${data.registros_por_pagina}
`);
return sesiones;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

}

lo paso al controlador:

```
export const busqueda_sesiones = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const { body } = req;

    const total_sesiones = await sesiones_busqueda_count(body.busqueda);
    const datos_pagina = {
        pagina: parseInt(body.pagina),
        total_registros: total_sesiones.numero,
        registros_por_pagina: 5,
        busqueda: body.busqueda
    };
    const datos_paginacion = paginacion_tabla(datos_pagina);
    const sesion = await sesiones_busqueda(datos_paginacion);
    const page_data = {
        datos_paginacion: datos_paginacion,
        sesion: sesion
    }
    res.json(page_data);
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
    next();
}
```

}

muestro y convierto en mi JavaScript:

```
  const buscar_sesiones = async (e, pagina = 1) => {
try {
    if (e.target.value.trim() === "") {
        tabla_sesiones.style.display = "table-row-group";
        tabla_sesiones_resultados.style.display = "none"
        tabla_paginada_sesiones.style.display = "none";
        paginacion_sesiones.style.display = 'block';
        tabla_busqueda_sesiones.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }
    tabla_sesiones.style.display = "none";
    tabla_sesiones_resultados.style.display = "table-row-group"
    tabla_paginada_sesiones.style.display = "none";
    paginacion_sesiones.style.display = 'none';
    tabla_busqueda_sesiones.style.display = 'table-row-group';
    tabla_paginada_sesiones.style.display = "block";
    const form_data = {
        busqueda: e.target.value,
        pagina: pagina
    }

    const response = await fetch(`${base_url}api/sesiones/busqueda_sesiones`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams(form_data)
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("result",result);
    let result_HTML = "";
    if(result.sesion.length === 0) {
        tabla_busqueda_sesiones.innerHTML = `
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"colspan="10">No hay resultados.</td>
            </tr>
        `;
        tabla_paginada_sesiones.style.display = "none";
        return;
    }
        result.sesion.forEach(sesiones =>{
            console.log("hora z",result.sesion);
            const session_entrada = formato_fecha(sesiones.session_start);
            const session_salida = sesiones.session_end ? formato_fecha(sesiones.session_end) : "-- / -- / ---- --:--:--";
            const sesion_ultimo_monitoreo = formato_fecha(sesiones.sesion_ultimo_monitoreo);
            console.log("sesion entrada",session_entrada, "sesion salida",session_salida, "sesion monitoreo", sesion_ultimo_monitoreo);
            result_HTML +=
            `
            <tr>
                <td>${sesiones.user_name}</td>
                <td>${session_entrada}</td>
                <td>${session_salida}</td>
                <td>${sesion_ultimo_monitoreo}</td>
                <td>${sesiones.sesion_status}</td>
            </tr>
        `; 
    });
    tabla_busqueda_sesiones.innerHTML = result_HTML;
    generar_paginacion(result.datos_paginacion);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

}